# Не работает клавиатура в BIOS на ноутбуке

Tags: ubuntu, windows-10, bios

Пытаюсь поставить на ноут Ubuntu. При заходе в bios,столкнулся с проблемой,что  не работает клавиатура(не реагирует на нажатие клавиш). Кто сталкивался с подобной проблемой?

Comment: Попробуйте погуглить "keyboard in bios not working". И добавьте к запросу название производителя ноутбука.

Comment: Попробуйте поставить USB-клавиатуру.

Answer (score 0):

Была такая проблема однажды на ноутбуке ASUS в UEFI BIOS.
Проблема решилась с помощью перепрошивки BIOS на новейшую версию.
P.S. Пришлось колдовать с автоматической перепрошивкой с созданием загрузочной флешки.